# Eclipse Virgo 3.0.2 shutdown automatically on AWS Amazon Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, osgi, eclipse-virgo

I installed Eclipse Virgo 3.0.2 on a AWS Amazon instance with Ubuntu 10.02 LT Version

The problem is that the Eclipse Virgo with my custom bundles start correctly, but in a few minutes or hours the amount of time is variable the instance of Virgo stop automatically.

I used the `virgo` scripts to startup the instance but with this changes, to reserve more memory to the VM to startup:

```
# set VM menory for konekti
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx1024M -Xms512m"
export JAVA_OPTS
```

I only paste the logs, when the `virgo` instance start to shutdown:

```
[2013-01-08 21:59:12.550] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       o.e.v.kernel.dmfragment.internal.ApplicationContextShutdownBean   Setting timeout to 0 for proxy 'org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean@865620' of application context 'OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=org.springframework.osgi.extender, config=bundleentry://110.fwk7578443/META-INF/spring/extender/kernel-dmfragment-context.xml): startup date [Tue Jan 08 19:39:15 UTC 2013]; root of context hierarchy' 
[2013-01-08 21:59:12.551] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       o.e.v.kernel.dmfragment.internal.ApplicationContextShutdownBean   Setting timeout to 0 for proxy 'org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean@28979b' of application context 'OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.dm, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml): startup date [Tue Jan 08 19:39:15 UTC 2013]; root of context hierarchy' 
[2013-01-08 21:59:12.551] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       o.e.v.kernel.dmfragment.internal.ApplicationContextShutdownBean   Setting timeout to 0 for proxy 'org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean@f96b40' of application context 'OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml): startup date [Tue Jan 08 19:39:17 UTC 2013]; root of context hierarchy' 

... 

[2013-01-08 21:59:16.498] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.view.web.form_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.498] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.openlayerswrapper_1.2.0 [276]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.498] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.openlayerswrapper_1.2.0, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.498] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.localtiontextfield_1.2.1 [275]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.498] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.localtiontextfield_1.2.1, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.498] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.customfield_1.0.0 [274]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.499] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.customfield_1.0.0, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.499] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.view.web.form_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [273]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.499] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.view.web.form_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.499] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.splitbutton_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [272]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.499] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.splitbutton_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.499] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.sliderlayout_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [271]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.499] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.sliderlayout_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.500] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.formbinder_2.1.2 [270]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.500] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.formbinder_2.1.2, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.500] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.confirmdialog_1.1.1 [269]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.500] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.confirmdialog_1.1.1, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.500] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.buttongroup_1.2.0 [268]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.500] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.com.vaadin.addons.buttongroup_1.2.0, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.500] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.view.addon_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [267]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.501] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.view.addon_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.501] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.view.kernel_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, Service 526, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.501] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.view.kernel_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [266]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.501] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.view.kernel_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.502] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.report_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [264]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.502] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.report_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.502] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.knowledge.service.impl_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [263]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.502] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.knowledge.service.impl_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.502] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.knowledge.service.api_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [262]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.502] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.knowledge.service.api_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.503] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.knowledge.service.impl_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [261]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.503] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.knowledge.service.impl_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.503] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.knowledge.service.api_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [260]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.503] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.knowledge.service.api_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.503] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.knowledge_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, Service 517, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.504] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.knowledge_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [259]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.504] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.knowledge_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.504] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.service.impl_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [258]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.504] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.service.impl_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.504] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.service.api_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [257]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.504] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.workshoptrack.service.api_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.505] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.service.sensor.impl_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [256]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.505] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.service.sensor.impl_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.505] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'com.thingtrack.konekti.service.sensor.api_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT [255]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.505] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.thingtrack.konekti.service.sensor.api_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:16.505] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'org.springframework.web.servlet_3.0.5.RELEASE [254]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 

... 

[2013-01-08 21:59:21.327] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.3.0.v20110124-0830, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.327] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.springframework.osgi.extender_1.2.1, Service 57, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.327] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'org.springframework.osgi.extender_1.2.1 [30]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.327] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.springframework.osgi.extender_1.2.1, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.327] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker         Bundle 'org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.agent.dm_3.0.2.RELEASE [28]' has stopped. Removing its related tracking state. 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.327] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.agent.dm_3.0.2.RELEASE, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.327] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 69, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.328] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.328] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.repository_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 54, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.328] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.repository_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 55, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.328] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.repository_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 97, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.328] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.repository_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 53, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.328] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.repository_3.0.2.RELEASE, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.328] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient_3.1.0, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.328] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec_1.3.0, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.329] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.util.parser.manifest_3.0.2.RELEASE, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.329] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.util.math_3.0.2.RELEASE, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.329] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.util.io_3.0.2.RELEASE, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.329] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.util.common_3.0.2.RELEASE, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.329] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.100.v20110110, Service 52, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.329] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.100.v20110110, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.329] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.util.osgi_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 51, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.util.osgi_3.0.2.RELEASE, BundleEvent STOPPED 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 43, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 61, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 63, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 65, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 67, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 64, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 45, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 66, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.330] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 42, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 47, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 39, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 44, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 46, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 38, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 68, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 37, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 41, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING 
[2013-01-08 21:59:21.331] INFO  SGiLogServiceListener@1049d3 org.osgi.service.log.LogService                                   Bundle org.eclipse.virgo.medic.core_3.0.2.RELEASE, Service 62, ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING
```

That you see there are any ERROR inside, only INFO logs, it's apper that AWS shutdown my instance, but is it possible? 
Anybody know what happend? The VM is  that shutdown my instance  or is any bug of Virgo?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to start virgo on startup, if you start it from SSH it will get killed after sometime you close the SSH connection. See something like https://gist.github.com/tarelli/4369545